# error Jparepository java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Error:

```
2018-12-06 18:18:34.601  WARN 2304 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]
```

Entity:

```
 public class DBFonts {
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String nameFont;
    @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(
                name="SFont",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SFont_id")
        )
        @Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Column(length=100000)
        private List<byte[]> standartFonts;
        }
```

repo:

```
    public interface FontRepo extends JpaRepository<DBFonts,Long> {
      List<byte[]> findByStandartFonts(Long sfontid);

    }
```

main:

```
 List<byte[]> dBfontSt = fontRepo.findByStandartFonts(2L);
```

date standartFonts:

[image]

What could be the problem?Any information will be useful)

Answer (score 1):

JpaRepository `findByStandartsFonts` method requires `List<byte[]>` type parameter. It cannot accept `Long` type. By the way, the lifecycle of the value-type collection is entirely controlled by its owning entity. So it is not possible to query directly on `@CollectionTable`. Try to introduce a new entity and appropriate association.

Comment: thank,and perhaps instead of creating a new entity, use Hibernate?

Comment: "By the way, the lifecycle of the value-type collection is entirely controlled by its owning entity"can be more?